# How do I Disable Crashlytics Email Notifications on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I currently keep on receiving emails about crashes.

- Is there anyway I could disable email notifications from Firebase Crashlytics by toggling it on and off?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you visit your [Alert Subscription overview page](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/subscriptions/overview), you can disable email alerts.

After choosing a project, you can select your alert options for each service. For example, Crashlytics has the following options:

[image: crashlytics email options]

This page can be reached again by clicking the bell icon in the top right, then the gear icon.

Comment: Is this option shared between all project users or just the current user? I don't want to disable email alert for the entire project just for my current email can I do that?

Comment: @OmarMneimneh I believe it is only the current user, as you can do it without admin permissions.

Comment: Is there a way I can disable the notification for other users?

Answer (score 0):

when having linked the app to Fabric; one can configure that in the [notification settings](https://fabric.io/settings/notifications).

there even is a `stop watching` button, to mute an app altogether.